# Deploy Quasar SSR vue/node app to Firebase Hosting

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting, quasar

I've tried many approches to upload and run the node/vue project on the firebase hosting, but didn't succeed.

I've followed [official guidelines on Firecast youtube channel](https://youtu.be/LOeioOKUKI8?t=402), but it seems that I'm missing something.

My vue.js app in SSR mode works fine on localhost. It is slighly different than the basic node/express app. Once deployed to Firebase Hosting, I have Error 404 page.
([Quasar Documentation on SSR deploy](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/deploying))

I've build an app with `quasar build -m ssr`, which generates a new folder `dist/ssr` folder.
[image]

`firebase.json` file in the root of my project where I've initiated a firebase project with `firebase init` contains following lines:

```
  {
    "hosting": {
      "public": "dist/ssr",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "app"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Before deploying to firebase hosting, I'm trying to test it with `firebase serve` but when I access a page on `localhost:5000` I get an error 404 or No-content.

Anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is the solution I came up with.

I've made a project template on github: https://github.com/danieltorscho/gcp-quasar

1. After having initialized your firebase project in the root of your project folder with `firebase init`, open the generated `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/ssr",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "ssrapp" // <- This NAME should be the same as in /src-ssr/index.js
    }]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "dist/ssr"
  }
}
```

2. Install dependencies `yarn add firebase-admin firebase-functions`
3. Open and edit `/src-ssr/index.js`:

```
// BEGINNING OF THE FILE
const functions = require('firebase-functions') // <---- ADD FIREBASE FUNCTIONS

const
  express = require('express'),
  compression = require('compression')

const
  ssr = require('quasar-ssr'),
  extension = require('./extension'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000
...
...
...
// END OF THE FILE

// COMMENT or DELETE following 3 lines of app.listen function
// app.listen(port, () => {
//   console.log(`Server listening at port ${port}`)
// })

exports.ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app) // <- "ssrapp" name is the same as in firebase.json
```

4. Now build the SSR app with `quasar build -m ssr`
5. In your terminal, go to `./dist/ssr/` and run `yarn install` to install node modules.
6. Finally go back to your root path "./" and test before deployment with `firebase serve` command. It will be available at port 5000 as usual. localhost:5000

Answer (score 1):

Using `http://localhost:5000` in your browser is going to request the file called "index.html" from your public folder, which is `dist/ssr`.  From what you've shown here, there is no index.html in that folder.  I see "index.js" and "template.html".

You're either going to have to do one of the following:

- Arrange for an index.html to be created in dist/ssr
- Or, change your URL to locate an HTML file that exists under dist/ssr
- Or, change your public folder configuration to point to a folder that has the content you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't help, tried to point to template, install dependencies, changed index.js to run pure express server along the firebase functions, still gives me an error 404.

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you did that isn't working the way you expect, I can't be of any further assistance.  You probably still just don't have an appropriate index.html in place.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to show more what I've done. What I can only tell is that there is no guidline on how to deploy a quasar ssr app to firebase hosting. I've tried to deploy pure node/express app and it worked, but here with quasar auto-generated /dist/ssr/index.js file I'm not sure how to connect firebase.json configuration file with this index.js of dist/ssr